# Dropdown Multiselect doesnt work inside Modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-multiselect

I am appending some options to the Select with id = "dropdownPerson" present in this modal:

```
<div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Results</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactModalPhoneInput" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled/>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="btnChangePhone">Change</button>

                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <h5>No Person Associated</h5>
                        <div>
                            <select id="dropdownPerson" title="Choose a Person"></select>
                            <div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="updatePerson()">Update</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

When I initialize it using **$('#dropdownPerson').multiselect()** it says that it doesn't have any options.
However, if I dont initialize it as a multiselect I can see that my options have been appended to the selected (it just stays as a standard bootstrap select)

```
$('#dropdownPerson').multiselect();


for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let elem = document.createElement("option");
        elem.textContent = i;
        document.getElementById("dropdownPerson").appendChild(elem);    
}

I am also adding the following to the html:

<!-- jQuery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap-->
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Multiselect-->
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Imports-->
<script src="../js/globals.js"></script>
<script src="../js/utils.js"></script>
<script src="../js/functions.js"></script>
<script src="../js/populate.js"></script>

enter code here
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Have you Tried executing `$('#dropdownPerson').multiselect();` after your for loop?? Because if you do it before for loop then it wont find any options as it won't be there.

Comment: Now that I realized it, you are correct. I was calling multiselect() before inserting the elements in the array. Thank you!